# what functions do I need to use to solve this using R?

Tags: r, data-analysis

Suppose if I have data with field name "Job", how can I combine Jobs with less than 5% of records into a field called "other"

Comment: Hi @Moni, in order for the community to help you, you should provide more information. In particular, you should provide an example of the data you're using. You could do this by running `dput(YOURDATA)` and pasting the output into the question. Without this extra context, your question is much harder to answer.

Comment: @BrianLang Question is simple: how to collapse levels with less than 5% records into one level. Do we really need an example here?

Comment: Surely every question requiring a code solution (in R at least) can be improved and clarified by the inclusion of an example.

Comment: But not every question needs to be improved or clarified. Especially basic and general questions like this one. Plus, demanding from new contributors some extra effort, which we do not actually need to provide help, may discourage them.

Answer (score 2):

`forcats::fct_lump` maybe?

Let's generate some toy data:

```
library(magrittr)
library(forcats)

Job<-rep(LETTERS[1:10], 1:10) %>% factor
```

And see its distribution:

```
Job %>% table %>% prop.table

         A          B          C          D          E          F          G          H          I          J 
0.01818182 0.03636364 0.05454545 0.07272727 0.09090909 0.10909091 0.12727273 0.14545455 0.16363636 0.18181818
```

To finally collapse levels that accunt for less than 5% into category we call `other`

```
Job %>% fct_lump(prop=0.05, other_level = 'other')

 [1] other other other C     C     C     D     D     D     D     E     E     E     E     E     F     F     F     F     F     F     G     G     G     G     G     G     G    
[29] H     H     H     H     H     H     H     H     I     I     I     I     I     I     I     I     I     J     J     J     J     J     J     J     J     J     J    
Levels: C D E F G H I J other
```